# Setting Up Facebook Advanced Matching Manually?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pixel, ads

Ive tried to setup Advanced matching manually on my Wordpress site. Events manager is telling me to increase coverage for email, first name and last name.

[FB events manager says to increase coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq4fM.png)

This is the code ive added to the pixel.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'PIXEL-CODE', {
  em: '{user-email}',
  ph: '{user-phone-number}', 
  fn: '{user-first-name}',
  ln: '{user-last-name}',
});
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=PIXEL-CODE&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

My question is

1. does the pixel track the email, first name, last name on PageView even when a visitor just views the page or do they need to provide input like in the forms for the pixel to track their data?
2. For the em: '{user-email}' part, do i need to replace {user-email} with the input field name in my form for it to work? Is my code correct?
3. Assuming everything is working and setup correctly, should i see immediate results especially in the email, first name, last name being 100%?

Thanks to those who could help.

Comment: _"do i need to replace {user-email} with the input field name in my form for it to work?"_ - no, you need to replace it with an actual email address. This really applies more to systems where you have a logged-in user, so that you know data such as their email address already. Since the parameters are passed with the `init` action, you can't really make them fill out a form first, and then track that data for the same page they are on - unless you were to _delay_ the pixel init until then, which is probably not a good idea at all.